# How to locate digits and capital letters in a Python string

Tags: python

Is there a way to locate capital letters and digits in a string?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
# Imports


import random

# Variables

my_score = 0
loop = True

# start

while loop == True:

  username = input("Enter your username")

  has_digit = False
  has_upper = False
```

I tried searching Google but I couldn't find anything that seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to work"—but _what_ doesn't seem to work? What part of this code tries to identify capital letters or digits? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

has_upper = True if re.search('[A-Z]', username) else False
has_digit = True if re.search('\d', username) else False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any()` for this:

```py
has_digit = any(c.isdigit() for c in username)
has_upper = any(c.isupper() for c in username)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `any`, `isdigit`, and `isupper`:

```
>>> while True:
...     username = input("Enter your username")
...     if any(c.isdigit() for c in username):
...         print("there's a digit in that")
...     if any(c.isupper() for c in username):
...         print("there's a capital letter in that")
...
Enter your usernamebob
Enter your usernameBob
there's a capital letter in that
Enter your usernameBob123
there's a digit in that
there's a capital letter in that
```

If you want to get the number of each type of character, use `sum` instead of `any`:

```
>>> while True:
...     username = input("Enter your username: ")
...     print(f"There are {sum(c.isupper() for c in username)} capital letters in that.")
...     print(f"There are {sum(c.isdigit() for c in username)} digits in that.")
...
Enter your username: bob
There are 0 capital letters in that.
There are 0 digits in that.
Enter your username: Bob
There are 1 capital letters in that.
There are 0 digits in that.
Enter your username: Bob123
There are 1 capital letters in that.
There are 3 digits in that.
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers suggest, you can use `any()` function to traverse the string and search for digits and specific characters. But to know if there is a numeric character or a digit in your string, `.isalnum()` results in an alternative that you can use in many string related problems:

```
username = input("Enter your username")
has_digit = username.isalnum()
has_upper = any(c.isupper() for c in username)
```